# Has to login twice: angular js

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I came across the solution for this problem but i may not be implementing it properly or it isn't the solution. The problem is that i need to login twice.
 I tried using `$scope.$apply()` but i did not know if i was using it right.
my login controller:

```
app.controller('loginctrl',['$rootScope','$scope','$http','$state','$cookies',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$state,$cookies){
var cookietoken= $cookies.get('Token');

if(cookietoken)
{
    alert('You are already logged in!');
    $state.go('home');
}
else
{
    $scope.user={
        username:"",
        password:"",
        rememberme:""
    };
    $scope.showerror=false;

    $scope.login = function(){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:$rootScope.apiend+'login',
            data:$scope.user
        })
        .success(function(result){
            console.log(result);

        }).error(function(){
            alert('something looks wrong.');
        });
    };
}
```

}]);

EDIT:
the page is initially entering into the error method for the first time and showing the success method for the second time

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this code and how it doesn't work? is there an error message in the browser's javascript console?

Comment: no error message and i want to login through this page and it works perfect except for one reason: the page reloads after the first time i try to log in and logs in the second time'

Comment: Do you have CSRF on the webpage and supported at the server side? Please add more details on the form are you submitting for the login page and server configuration for that.

Comment: @OlgaKhylkouskaya i disabled CSRF on the server side, since i couldn't figure an error . I am using laravel 5.2 and there was a constant error:  `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but I assume that when the `login` function is called, it successfully logs you in "on the server part" but the `success` method on the client does nothing more than write the result in console and when you try the second time, it checks you are already logged (checking the cookietoken) and if so, sends you to the "home" page.

If that is the case, then you just need to add the line `$state.go('home');` once the login has been successful, in the `success` method:

```
app.controller('loginctrl',['$rootScope','$scope','$http','$state','$cookies',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$state,$cookies){
var cookietoken= $cookies.get('Token');

if(cookietoken)
{
    alert('You are already logged in!');
    $state.go('home');
}
else
{
    $scope.user={
        username:"",
        password:"",
        rememberme:""
    };
    $scope.showerror=false;

    $scope.login = function(){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:$rootScope.apiend+'login',
            data:$scope.user
        })
        .success(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $state.go('home');              /* <--  add this line here */

        });
    };
}
}]);
```

Comment: nope! this is not what it is happening. I tried though. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Do you see the result printed in the javascript console? or at least the ajax request sent to the server? is the Token cookie set from the first login attempt?

Comment: console stays empty for the first time and result is being printed for the second time and also no cookie is being set for the first attempt . I had modified my code a bit. YES! the ajax request is being sent to the server

Comment: Can you please update if you find a solution, I'm curious.